# What's the correct way to reuse connections in case of PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried restoring connections in $_SESSION,

but can only reuse for one user.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean be "reuse connections"? A connection is a socket being opened to the server..of course you can't store it in $_SESSION. It still would have to reconnect, so it would be pointless anyways. The closest you can come to it is [persistent connections](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php).

Comment: reuse means:not close the connection after each request.So next request will save time.

Comment: Well persistent connections do that. You still have to specify the connection like you normally would though; there is no other solution.

Answer (score 5):

Read about `mysql_pconnect()`.

Unfortunately, persistent connection is not stable in PDO and not supported by MySQLi.

Persistent connections save time when the database server is **not** in the localhost, but if it is, use of persistent connections is practically irrelevant.

Comment: Also, if you are using PDO you can do something like:
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

Comment: According to the PDO documentation, it is not entirely safe or recommended.

Answer (score 1):

use [mysql_pconnect](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-pconnect) rather than mysql_connect